# C# print screen scrollable control

Tags: c#, printing, screen, region, scrollable

i have a control that is the plotter which is scrollable. After the plotter has finished plotting, it is able to scroll just like this:
[image]

My plotter is a real-time plotter i.e. meaning it plots as time goes by and it's not a static plotter(one which u put in the values manually). After I've stopped the plotter, I'm able to scroll around the plotter to see the results. However, I want to save the plotter into an image, which I'm trying to do using print screen method. But what I was able to capture is only the visible part of the plotter, but not the non-visible part of the plotter(which is because it needs scrolling). I hope it's clearer now.
The code for the print screen is:

```
// Set the bitmap object to the size of the screen
        bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(panel2.Bounds.Width, panel2.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        // Create a graphics object from the bitmap
        gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

        Point p = this.PointToScreen(new Point(panel2.Bounds.X, panel2.Bounds.Y));
        gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(p.X, p.Y, 0, 0,
                         panel2.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);


        SaveFileDialog saveImageDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveImageDialog.Title = "Select output file:";
        saveImageDialog.Filter = "JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif";
        if (saveImageDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            bmpScreenshot.Save(saveImageDialog.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Code please? If it is a control call [`Invalidate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate(VS.71).aspx) on scroll events.

Comment: You mean when you scroll the control, you see empty space? What code are you using to draw the plot?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10201852/how-to-print-window-form-usig-cnet.aspx you should call the Win32 API PrintWindow.

Comment: well my interpretation of his question is that he is able to plot what he needs to plot but he cannot make a print screen of the non visible area of the control, it's an interpretation and can be wrong but since he talks about print screen in the title...

Comment: fair enough, I try to push OP to give a better question to avoid interpretation :) Ignore my comments.

Comment: Thanks Davide, I've updated my question. Your interpretation is correct, however the link that you posted talks about the actual 'printing' which I do not want to do.